# Edits in List not being saved when partial view loaded MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC.  I have a view which displays the products attached to a `Quote` (the `QuoteDetails`).  I also have an `Ajax.ActionLink)_` for "Add product" which loads a partial view for another product to be entered.  The problem is that when the partial view is loaded, edits to the other products not in the partial view are not saved.  If no partial view is loaded, edits to the listed products are saved just fine.

Here is the relevant code for the main view:

```
@model CMSUsersAndRoles.Models.QuoteViewModel
....
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ....
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CustomerId)

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuoteId)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QuoteId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QuoteId)

    .... // more controls for properties of Quote

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuoteDetail)
    <div id="QuoteDetails">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.QuoteDetail.Count; i++)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.QuoteDetail[i].QuoteId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            ....     
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QuoteDetail[i].SKU, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly", @id = "SKU", @class = "form-control", style = "width: 100px" } })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QuoteDetail[i].Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control amount", style = "width: 95px" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QuoteDetail[i].Amount)

            .... // more for controls for properties of QuoteDetail

            @Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "DeleteProduct", "QuoteViewModel", new { quoteId = Model.QuoteDetail[i].QuoteId, quoteDetailId = (Model.QuoteDetail[i].QuoteDetailId) },
                new AjaxOptions
                {
                    HttpMethod = "POST",
                    Confirm = "Are you Sure You Want to Delete " + Model.QuoteDetail[i].ProductName,
                }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash" })
                    </div>
            }
           @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Subtotal, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control subTotal", style = "width: 100px; float:right; clear:left; text-align:right" } })

           @Ajax.ActionLink("Add product", "AddProduct", "QuoteViewModel", new { quoteId = Model.QuoteId, quoteDetailId = (Model.QuoteDetail.Count + 1) }, 
               new AjaxOptions
               {
                   UpdateTargetId = "QuoteDetails",
                   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter
               })
            }
```

Here is the partial view:

```
@model CMSUsersAndRoles.Models.QuoteDetail

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditQuoteDetail";
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="row" class="row">
        <table>
            @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("quoteDetail"))
            {
                <tr>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.QuoteId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SKU, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly", @id = "SKU", @class = "form-control", style = "width: 100px" } })
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductId, new SelectList(ViewBag.ProductData, "ProductId", "Name"), "---Select one---", new { style = "width: 300px !important", htmlAttributes = new { @id = "ProductName", @class = "ProductList" } });

                    .... // more controls for properties of QuoteDetail

                    @Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "DeleteProduct", "QuoteViewModel", new { quoteId = Model.QuoteId, quoteDetailId = (Model.QuoteDetailId) },
                          new AjaxOptions
                          {
                              HttpMethod = "POST",
                              Confirm = "Are you Sure You Want to Delete " + Model.ProductName,
                          }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash" })
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
```

And here is the controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(QuoteViewModel qvm, 
    [Bind(Include = "CustomerId,SalesRep,FirstName,LastName,Company,Address1,Address2,City,State,PostalCode,WorkPhone,CellPhone,Email,Discount,PaymentTerms")] Customer customer,
    [Bind(Include = "QuoteId,QuoteDetailId,ProductId,ProductName,Amount,ListPrice,Discount,Price")] List<QuoteDetail> quoteDetails,
    [Bind(Include = "QuoteId,CustomerId,Subtotal,Tax,Total,QuoteDate,GoodUntil,QuoteSent,DateApproved,DateOrdered")] Quote quote)      
{
    ....
}
```

Can anyone help with this?  Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using 2 different techniques here to generate your collection which is causing the issue.

In the main view you have a `for` loop to generate controls for existing items which is generating the zero-based consecutive indexers, which is what the `DefaultModelBinder` uses by default. Your html will include `name` attributes that are for example

```
<input name="QuoteDetail[0].QuoteId"..../>
<input name="QuoteDetail[1].QuoteId"..../>
<input name="QuoteDetail[2].QuoteId"..../>
```

But then you add new items using the `BeginCollectionItem` helper method which generates the collection indexer as a `Guid` so that new inputs will be (where `xxx` is a `Guid`)

```
<input name="QuoteDetail[xxxx].QuoteId"..../>
```

and also includes a

```
<input name="QuoteDetail.Index" value="xxxx" ... />
```

which is used by the `DefaultModelBinder` to match non zero-based non consecutive indexers. You cannot use both techniques.

To solve this, you can either add an input for the indexer in the `for` loop

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.QuoteDetail.Count; i++)
{
    ....
    <input type="hidden" name="QuoteDetail.Index" value="@i" />
}
```

or change the loop to use the partial view containing the `BeginCollectionItem` method in each iteration

```
@foreach(var item in Model.QuoteDetail)
{
    @Html.Partial("xxxx", item) // replace xxxx with the name of your partial
}
```

Comment: I used solution 2, and it worked like a charm.  Thanks!